# How to get detail app service statisics (Web App detail) from GCP using .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'm developing CMP where it has to collect some data from GCP and i have to collect app services statistics from GCP. I'm confused on which library do i have to use.

Comment: For the uninitiated, what is CMP?

Comment: Edit and elaborate your question, provide also the code that you are working on and the documentation that you are following.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).